# WebAPI Certificates and Authentication - ELI5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm sure I'm missing some key facts, but I can get those for you.  I'm really confused on how this all needs to work:

- Server 1 – IIS 8, Hosting a Vendor’s WebAPI, Anonymous and Windows Authentication.  Providers are Negotiate, NTLM.  Https and a signed certificate  (Cert1).
- Server 2 – IIS8, New WebAPI connecting to Server1’s WebAPI.  I’m assuming I need to store Cert1 on Server 2.  We will have another Certificate, https (Cert2)
- Server 3 – IIS 8, Website connecting to server 2’s webAPI.
- User – Browser connecting to Server 3, Windows Authentication Only.
  Every server and the user’s browser connects to the same Active Directory.

I have access to Server1’s web.config to change bindings, but not the code.  In Visual Studio 2013, when I add the service reference for Server 2, the web.config is added like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICoreWebService">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://dave.domain.com/webService/CoreWebService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICoreWebService" contract="Dave.ICoreWebService" name="WSHttpBinding_ICoreWebService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="Server1ServiceAccount@dave.domain.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

This is Server1's WebAPI web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <!-- The following block is used for secure connection (HTTPS)-->
    <binding name="DaveServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Dave.WebService.CoreWebService" behaviorConfiguration="DaveWebServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DaveWebServiceBinding" contract="Dave.WebService.ICoreWebService" />
    <endpoint address="wauth" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DaveWebServiceBindingWauth" contract="Dave.WebService.ICoreWebService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DaveWebServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Dave.WebService.WebServiceAuthValidator,Dave.WebService" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

1. I’m having trouble with how the certificates work between Server 1 and Server 2.  I just need to download Cert1 and store it on Server2?  Then refer to that certificate when I make the call.  This code isn't finding the certificate:

   ```
   svc.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
               StoreName.TrustedPublisher,
               X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "CN = dave.domain.com, OU = ZZ123, O = Dave, Inc., L = Chicago, S = Illinois, C = US");
   ```
2. How can I bubble up the windows authentication from the user to server1?  The vendor’s API will Authenticate through that message.

Right now, I’m able to browse to the service locally, but I’ve been stuck on Server 2 and getting the certificate.  I want to make sure I’m storing  and referencing it correctly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Subject Name needed to be the domain, and I used the MMC to make sure the certificate was where it should be.

MMC -> certificates (you may need to add them in your snap-in)

Trusted People -> Certificates.

Hope that helps someone.